# Draw an histogram from pandas column with datetype

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': ['a','b','c','d','e'],
                    'B': ['1970','1970','1980','1980','1972']
                    })
```

I converted column B to datetime:

```
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.B).year, format='%Y')

 Out[13]: 
       A          B
    0  a 1970-01-01
    1  b 1970-01-01
    2  c 1980-01-01
    3  d 1980-01-01
    4  e 1972-01-01
```

Now I want to draw an histogram that shows year on x-axis and count on the y-axi i.e. for 1970 hist should show 2, for 1980 hist should show 2 and so on.
How to do this...

Comment: Total count or count per unique value in `A`?  If it's the former: `df.groupby(df.B.dt.year).A.size().plot(kind='bar')`

Comment: Well I used this df.groupby(df.B.dt.year).count().plot(kind="bar") but I am getting two bars for each count with a label of A and B. Not sure why?

Comment: Because you aren't selected a series to count by.

Comment: @user3483203 Ok..could you please explain logic of your solution. It worked. Thanks. But I don't get why you are using A.size().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': ['a','b','c','d','e'],
                    'B': ['1970','1970','1980','1980','1972']
                    })
df['B'].hist(grid=False)
```

Output:

[image]

OR

```
df['B'].value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

And

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'A': ['a','b','c','d','e'],
                    'B': ['1970','1970','1980','1980','1972']
                    })
df['B'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.B).year, format='%Y')
df['B'].dt.year.value_counts(sort=False).plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I need to draw histogram on datetime type in col B. If I tried your first sol I was getting a histogram which is kind of continuous over 1970, 1971 etc.

Comment: @DaveM See update using the .dt accessor for datetime dtype.